# How to inject a jar into Eclipse classpath? Not classpath of project, classpath of IDE and its plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-classpath

So many bugs that make it temporarily into Eclipse can be easily fixed by adding the missing jar to the classpath, except I can't actually fix the problem as when part of Eclipse fails because a plugin throws a NoClassDefFoundError, I don't know how to inject the missing jar into the plugin bundle or into the Eclipse IDE runtime, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You would probably use a plug-in fragment to do this, but it is very rare to need to do this. More often no class def and similar errors are due to out of date plug-ins not matching the current APIs - fixing that is often much more difficult. So perhaps you should give us an example error you are seeing.

Comment: I fixed it by installing a plugin to provide ICU4J to other plugins that need it but accidently did not declare that dependency, that plugin is called ICU4J